# meteor server insert data without login

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I want to create API that allow other app to insert(create) new data. But so far I tried, this not work with error message "User id is required", I know that happen because no login user found when insert new data. Is it possible to insert new data without login or any possible way to login from server side if using accounts-password's package or any possible way to make this work?

code on server

```
Picker.route('/createFood/:title', function(params, req, res, next) {
console.log('-> params : ',params);
let username = (new Date()).getTime().toString();
function createFood() {
  Fiber(function() {
    console.log("-> username : ",username);
    let acc = Accounts.createUser({
      username: username,
      email: username +'@foodie.com',
      password: username
    });  
  if (acc) {
      console.log("-> acc : ",acc);
      // Meteor.call("setUserId", acc);
      Menus.insert({
        title: params.title,
      }, function(err, foodId) {
        console.log("-> abs : ",Meteor.absoluteUrl());
        console.log("-> err : ",err.message);
        console.log("-> foodId : ",foodId);
        let code, result;
        if (err) {
          code = 500;
          result = {
            error: err.message
          }
        } else {
          code = 200;
          result = {
            foodId: foodId,
          }
        }
        res.setHeader( 'Content-Type', 'application/json' );
        res.statusCode = code;
        res.end( JSON.stringify( result ) );
      })
    }

  }).run();
}
if (params.title)
  createFood(); 
});
```

code food model, there is userId owner here

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
Menus.allow({
  insert: function() {
    return true;
  },
  update: function() {
    return true;
  },
  remove: function() {
    return true;
  },
  fetch: ['foodId'],
});
Menus.after.insert((userId, doc) => {
 ....
})
}
```

Comment: hey i am on the same issue, is there a solution?

Comment: @Gobliins Actually my problem lies on autoValue userId(this value will be null if there is no user login and my temporary solution at that time if using condition on its schema file, like `userId ? userId : "Ghost User"`). Maybe you can try to make sure that userId is not used as autoValue or required field when isInsert or isSet,. Hope this helpfull.

Comment: Ok then my Problem was a bit different. It came from the CollectionHooks where the userId (from Meteor) was undefined.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason why you can't insert to the database without logging in. You don't even have to include the accounts package if you don't want to .

Your current code doesn't insert unless a user is present, you can simplify it to this...

```
function createFood() {
      Menus.insert({
        title: params.title,
```

Comment: thanks for reply, but that's not solution i looking for :)
I found it recently that userID on autoValue is the main problem